# Excel formula to make value from a column in one spreadsheet appear in another spreadsheet if conditional formatting condition is met

Tags: excel

So I have a very specific problem in an excel workbook I am trying to make for work. I'm sorry I can't share it with you because it contains confidential information, so I will try to describe as best I can.

I have one sheet (Lets call it list A) in the workbook which has a list of a few appointments that require a particular resource. This list is automatically generated by a different piece of software and presents the duration of the appointment but not the start time. I have another sheet (list B) which comes from a different source, this has a list of all appointments and their start time but not their duration.

I currently have a conditional formatting rule in place to highlight any names in list b that also appear in list a, the purpose is to make it easy to see which appointments require a specific resource and at what time it is needed.

My problem is, I want to also display the duration of the appointment from list B on list A, but only next to the names that are highlighted by the conditional formatting. This problem is made more complicated by the fact that the way the two lists are generated makes them not necessarily in the same order.

The data from list A will change on a daily basis, so I need list B to update automatically.

To summarize I need a formula that will make a particular cell in list B equal to a particular cell in list A but only if a cell in the same row but different column appears in both lists.

Sorry if this is confusing, I appreciate any help provided.

Comment: use VLOOKUP or an INDEX & MATCH combination

Comment: `=IF(same_formula_as_conditional_formatting_condition, ..., ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming names are in ColumnA and times/durations in ColumnB in each sheet then:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'list A'!A:B,2,0),"")
```

should serve. Given *display the duration of the appointment from list B on list A, but only next to the names that are highlighted by the conditional formatting*  and *highlight any names in list b that also appear in list a* then a simpler version of the requirement seems to be "lookup durations for those names in List B that appear in List A".